# iptables couldn't load ipset match

Tags: networking, iptables

I tried to add some rules, but it kept failing.

Here is the rule like:

```
ipset create FABEDGE-PEER-CIDR hash:net

iptables -t nat -N FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING
iptables -t nat -A FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -m set --match-set FABEDGE-PEER-CIDR dst -j RETURN
```

Here is the result:

```
++ iptables -t nat -N FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING
iptables: Chain already exists.
++ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING
++ iptables -t nat -A FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -m set --match-set 
FABEDGE-PEER-CIDR dst -j RETURN
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Everytime this line

```
iptables -t nat -A FABEDGE-NAT-OUTGOING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -m set --match-set FABEDGE-PEER-CIDR dst -j RETURN
```

failed with the message: "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name."

I googled about this message, it seems iptables couldn't load ipset match, I checked the file "/proc/net/ip_tables_matches", here is the content:

```
cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
conntrack
conntrack
conntrack
addrtype
udplite
udp
tcp
addrtype
icmp
```

There should be a at lease one "set" in this file. Some articles mentioned iptables will load match module as required.

I use `lsmod | grep ip` and found ip_set module is loaded:

```
 lsmod | grep ip
iptable_raw             2525  0
ip_set_hash_net        33113  1
ip_set                 44480  1 ip_set_hash_net
```

I really have no idea what should I do, not a single clue.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

I should methon my iptables is v1.6.1, my kernel is 4.9.253-tegra and this kernel is cutomized.

Comment: Can you try without using the customized kernel? Those iptables lines work perfectly on a Centos 7 test system.

Comment: probably a custom kernel without support configured. the missing module would be xt_set (which is the iptables part) rather than ip_set (which is the... ipset part).

Comment: @ thrig those iptables rules works on my other computers too.

Comment: @A.B Yeah. I found that. But still I don't known why iptables didn't load xt_set module, I can saw it (xt_set.ko) in /lib/modules/4.9.253-tegra/kernel/net/netfilter/ folder

Comment: So can you load it manually with modprobe? Or even more manually with insmod?

Comment: @A.B modprobe failed because it couldn't find it under /lib/modules/4.9.253-tegra.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this self-compiled kernel missed some IPv6 modules, after my vendor provides another kernel, the problem is gone.